# Scala: What does mean to pass a Set to the map function of a set

Tags: scala

I've just seen I can do:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).map(Set(1))
```

which yields the result:

```
Set(true, false)
```

But I thought that the map function can only take another function not a new Set. If anything I'd expect this to return a set of sets. What's going on and what does the result mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> But I thought that the `map` function can only take another function not a new `Set`.

A `Set` *is* a function. It is a function from its elements to booleans: when you pass it an element, it tells you whether that element is part of the `Set`.

```
Set(1, 2, 3).map(Set(1))
```

Iterates over the `Set(1, 2, 3)`, passing each each element to the `Set(1)`. I.e. it first asks "is `1` a member of set `{1}`", which is `true`, then it asks the same question for `2` and `3`, which is `false`.

So, the result is `Set(true, false, false)`, which of course is just `Set(true, false)`.

Similarly, a sequence is a function from integers to elements, a map is a function from keys to values.

Answer (score 5):

`Set` is also function - it extends `Function1`. See **Inherited** section in Scaladoc:

http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/collection/immutable/Set.html

Answer (score 5):

- `Set[A]` extends `Function1[A, Boolean]`.
- `Map[K, V]` extends
  `PartialFunction[K, V]` which in turn extends `Function1[K, V]`.
- `Seq[A]` extends `PartialFunction[Int, A]` which in turn extends
  `Function1[Int, A]`.

So in Scala  collections library, sets, sequences, and maps are themselves functions.

- `apply` method in `Set[_]` tests set membership.
- `apply` method in `Map[_, _]`
  returns the value associated with the given key. Throws error if the
  key is absent.
- `apply` method in `Seq[_]` returns the element at given index. Throws error for an invalid index.

The following two are equivalent:

```
Set(1, 2, 3).map(Set(1))

Set(1, 2, 3).map(x => Set(1).contains(x))
```

So are the following two:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).collect(someMap)

Seq(1, 2, 3) collect { 
  case x if someMap contains x => someMap(x)
}
```

And also the following two:

```
Seq(1, 2, 3).map(someSeq)

Seq(1, 2, 3).map(x => someSeq(x))
```